# Android Studio Clone Physical Device?

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, cloning

I can't figure out how you can clone a physical device to a virtual one. My team needs to have copies of the physical properties as multiple people are working on separate fragments. Creating the device using the create hardware manager doesn't allow DPI changes so even though I match the length, width and screen size I cannot build a correct xml layout as the DPI is significantly different.

How do I clone a physical device for emulation and duplicate properties?

I've attached the clone and real devices below.

Virtual Device:

[image: Virtual Device]

Real Device

[image: Real Device]

There doesn't seem to be any way to match them or clone the physical device.

edit*
Picture real vs studio. Also display is on minimum
[image]
[image]

Comment: That `dp` value for your physical device does not make sense for the actual hardware. That device [has about 189 dpi actual density](https://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_tab_m8_(hd)-9825.php), and `mdpi` is a reasonable match for that. What the emulator is reporting would seem to be correct. Make sure that you have not fussed with anything in Settings on the actual tablet that might affect density, such as Display > Display size.

Comment: It doesn't work and is completely off in terms of size which is about right. The size after uploading to 800x1280 is almost double which correlates to the dp I see above. I've never touched any settings on the tablet, it's a default off the shelf device. Is there any way to clone properties from the physical device?

Comment: "Is there any way to clone properties from the physical device?" -- none that I am aware of. "it's a default off the shelf device" -- bear in mind that the manufacturer may have set a different default value for the display size.